# Flickr API で複数ライセンスを取得後、写真に紐付けてライセンスを表示することは可能？

Tags: flickr

**やりたいこと**
・Flickr API で取得した写真に紐付けて、ライセンスを表示させたい

---

**疑問点1**
・flickr.photos.searchリクエストする際、入力フィルタリングとしてライセンス指定は可能だが、戻り値にライセンスは含まれない？
・つまり、異なるライセンスの写真を取得した場合、写真に紐付けてライセンスを表示することは出来ない？
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

---

**疑問点2**
・flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo
・ライセンス取得できそうなAPIがあるのですが、これはどうやって使うのでしょうか？
・「flickr.photos.search」結果をさらにここへ投げる感じでしょうか？
・引数はapi_keyだけ？
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flickr.photos.search`の`extras`パラメータに`license`を追加すれば、検索結果にライセンスデータが含まれます。

`flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo`はFlickrで設定できるすべてのライセンスの一覧を取得するAPIです。

Comment: extrasパラメータにlicenseを追加したら取得できました